# How to flatten a RDD of tuple if it has an Option component

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatten, flatmap

I know if I want to transform `xs: RDD[Option[T]] to List[T]`, I simply write
`xs.flatten`

Now if I have a `rs:RDD[(Option[T], S)]` How do I transform this to
`RDD[T, S]` if there is any option other than calling filter and map.

Answer (score 1):

You can call map and use pattern matching:

```
rs.map {case (Some(t), s) => t->s}
```